# How to set a bitmap image into a imageview into android?

Tags: java, android, mysql, image, bitmap

I need to set a bitmap image into a image view.

I converted it into Base64 string and then I saved it into a db but when I retrieve the string and converted it I don't see the image.

This is the code to setting the **bitmap image** into the image view:

```
 Bitmap ProfileImage;
 ProfileImage = StringToBitMap(imageProfile);
 etImage.setImageBitmap(ProfileImage);
```

**imageProfile** is the base64 string retrieved from the db

the code of the function **StringToBitMap** is:

```
public Bitmap StringToBitMap(String encodedString) {
        try {
            byte[] encodeByte = Base64.decode(encodedString, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0,
                    encodeByte.length);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

What is wrong?

**logcat**:

[image]

Comment: Is there anything in the logcat? Sometimes it doesn't work because it is not a known color.

Comment: @TaylorCourtney done, I add logcat.. can you help me?

Comment: To me that seems like it is an unknown color. How are you choosing the color?

Comment: @TaylorCourtney the image is a photo of an emulated camera

Comment: What are your device specs?

Comment: @TaylorCourtney it's an emulator with android marshmallow

Comment: OK perfect, there is a known issue like this in 6.0 try updating to 6.0.1 or use an older version of android.

Comment: @TaylorCourtney it's 6.0 version x86 so what is the problem?

Comment: Yep, it should just be a bug that has since been fixed with the latest version.

Comment: @TaylorCourtney so people who insert a picture with their device should have no problems?

Comment: If it works with the latest version, yes.

Comment: ok if it works with android marshmallow 6.0.1 and next iis it ok? @TaylorCourtney

Comment: Correct it should be fine

Comment: ok thanks for your help @TaylorCourtney

Comment: Really I don't know because I don't have an emulator for 6.0.1 version so now I'll search it @TaylorCourtney

Comment: Did my suggestion help?